# Which IDE best for Wordpress Development?

Tags: customization, theme-customizer, ide

I am Developing a website in wordpress with WAMP, I am doing some style and code changes in wordpress template to make my site good.

I want to know best IDE to use with wordpress.

I had experience with eclipse and visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse with it's PHP Development Tool is good and recently I also experienced Visual Studio with it's PHP extension, that's also good. But nothing exceeds PHP Storm. Yes it's a paid IDE, but it's worth it. It's some core features like suggestion, code revision and error reporting is pretty awesome.

By doing some modifications you can also use Sublime Text 3 and Visual Studio Code as an IDE. They both have their packages dedicated for WordPress Development.

Netbeans is also awesome and it also has it's package or plugin dedicated for WordPress as far I know.

Though Adobe's Bracket emphasize on front-end it's possible too to code the backend part also using Bracket.

Now come to Aptana Studio. I don't have any personal experience with this, but as far I heard it's also pretty good. It's just a fork of Eclipse, so if you have experience with Eclipse. So if you've experience with Eclipse it'll seems familiar to you.

Those are some key editors and IDE's for PHP coding as well as WordPress. Basically it's your own choice what IDE you would prefer. If you're familiar with any of those above I would suggest you to stick with it and give PHP Storm a try. And if you need to edit some simple files it would be better if you use some light weight editor like Visual Studio Code or Sublime Text. Otherwise stick with your previous IDE.

Answer (score 0):

[PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/specials/phpstorm/phpstorm.html) is a really good PHP IDE. You can [set it up to work on WordPress](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/preparing-to-use-wordpress.html).